# Set id to nested Elements

Tags: xml, xslt

I have a question. 
Is there any easy way by using xslt to ad unique ids?
The element topicset shout only get an id if another topicset is nested.
To support my question, here is an example.

**Source XML**

```
<topicset>
   <topicset>
      <topicmeta></topicmeta>
      <topicset>
      <topicmeta></topicmeta>
      </topicset>
   </topicset>
   <topicset>
      <topicmeta></topicmeta>
   </topicset>
</topicset>
<topicset>
   <topicmeta></topicmeta>
</topicset>
<topicset>
   <topicmeta></topicmeta>
   <topicset>
      <topicmeta></topicmeta>
   </topicset>
</topicset>
```

**Result XML**

```
<topicset id="m54845">
   <topicset id="m54t45">
      <topicmeta></topicmeta>
      <topicset>
      <topicmeta></topicmeta>
      </topicset>
   </topicset>
   <topicset>
      <topicmeta></topicmeta>
   </topicset>
</topicset>
<topicset>
   <topicmeta></topicmeta>
</topicset>
<topicset id="m548z5">
   <topicmeta></topicmeta>
   <topicset>
      <topicmeta></topicmeta>
   </topicset>
</topicset>
```

Thanks alot

Comment: The answers will vary depending on XSLT 1 to XSLT 2 processors. The easiest and simplest would be `generate-id()`. BUT this ID is just unique in the current xml and will be the same with the same xml. If this is no problem, go for it.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

As pointed out in a comment, you can use `generate-id()` in XSLT (all versions) to generate a unique ID value for a node:

```
<xsl:transform xmlns:xsl="http://www.w3.org/1999/XSL/Transform" version="1.0">


    <xsl:template match="@*|node()">
        <xsl:copy>
            <xsl:apply-templates select="@*|node()"/>
        </xsl:copy>
    </xsl:template>

    <xsl:template match="topicset[topicset]">
        <topicset id="{generate-id()}">
            <xsl:apply-templates select="@* | node()"/>
        </topicset>
    </xsl:template>

</xsl:transform>
```

See online sample at http://xsltransform.net/94AbWB8.

Comment: Thanks, that's exactly what Im looking for